# Magento 1.9 change base image from phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, magento, phpmyadmin

i need help to change base image from database in phpMyAdmin.
The table where to make the changes is **catalog_product_entity_varchar**
as show in image attachment 
[phymyadmin table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvnfr.jpg)

i have to copy the same string from column **value** with **attribute_id** 78
to column **value** with **attribute_id** 77
where the **entity_id** is the same.
i need help create the right query
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should do the trick (backup before trying, it's an hint but I did not try it) :

```
UPDATE
    catalog_product_entity_varchar t1 
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar t2 
ON (t1.entity_id=t2.entity_id 
    AND t2.attribute_id=78 
    AND t1.attribute_id = 77)
SET t1.value = t2.value
```

But if you do not need to keep the attribute 77 you can delete all entry with 77 and then just `update catalog_product_entity_varchar set attribute_id = 78 where attribute_id = 77`